# Can Regular Expressions be used for the URL patterns in a Fluid app?

Tags: regex, macos, userscripts, fluid-mac-app-engine

URL patterns are very handy in [Fluid app](http://fluidapp.com) (a Site-specific Browser for OS X) to support scripts/styles for certain specified URLs, for example:
[image: Userstyles/Userscripts Window in Fluid app]

As [stated on the official website](http://fluidapp.com/list/):

> In the "Pattern" table below, you should add a pattern for any URL which you want to your Fluid App to visit. Star ("*") is a special character in this table. Star means "match anything here", and is a powerful way to easily include or exclude very large groups of URL patterns.

1. Can we use other characters such as "?" other than "*" to match the URLs?
2. Can regular expression be used instead?

Comment: Probably not, or they would have said so.  **Should be dirt simple for you to test** if you are already running Fluid (hint, hint).

Comment: I tried with nothing happening. Ask so because I am not sure whether I get the wrong RegExp or the app can't support it.

Comment: Try with `*google.com*`, then `*go?gle.com*`, then `*g[og]+le.com*`.  The first gives desired/baseline behavior, the second two answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Developer of Fluid here.

**Update:** **Yes!** Now you can use either simple *Wildcard* Patterns or full *Regular Expression* Patterns.

In Wildcard Patterns, star ("*") is a special Wildcard character that means "match anything here", and is a powerful way to easily include or exclude very large groups of URL patterns.

Alternatively, you can use full Regular Expression Patterns instead of Wildcard Patterns by wrapping your URL pattern in forward slashes / like: /http://google.com/.+/.

[Full details on the Whitelist feature in Fluid are here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52200/fluid-when-i-try-to-login-my-fluid-app-launches-the-default-browser-instead/52201#52201)

Comment: Glad to know that.  
Would you please also add a **Fluid App** tag here?  
I don't have the privilege.

Comment: Oh, hey Todd, I saw in a fairly recent Fluid update, in the release notes, something about the ability to **exclude** URLs. Do I simply put a `-` in front of the URL?